# MPI Fortran - method for averaging values across processors

Tags: arrays, sorting, duplicates, fortran, mpi

I have a double array that is chunked and distributed between processes. However, the chunks correspond to integer indexed locations which may be duplicated on other chunks. How can I average the double values which correspond to the duplicated integer location indices?

For instance, we have an array of size 9, split between two processors. A screen output of the values of the array on each processor would be

```
    proc=0
    idx value
    1   0.4324
    2   0.5
    3   0.7433

    proc=1
    idx value
    2  1.0
    4  0.432
    5  0.406
    6  0.843
```

The desired behavior for the code is to find that idx=2 is duplicated, and thus the average value for index location = 2 should be (0.5+1.0)/2.0 = 0.75.

My thought is to do an MPI_Send/Recv and compare the integers. Then, somehow, for those values duplicated, average the associated double values and replace the average in the array.

```
    sbuf(:) = indexarr(:)
    sbufdouble(:) = values(:)
    do iproc=1,nproc
       call MPI_Send(sbuf, size(sbuf), MPI_REAL, iproc... 
      ! Should I send the double values as well? 
    enddo

    do iproc=1,nproc
       call MPI_Recv(rbuf,...) 
    enddo

   !  Do some comparison between rbuf and the array chunk 
      indexarr owned by this processor

   !  If integers match, average the corresponding double values 
      between the two

   !  Replace the averaged value in indexarr(:)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! This is not a place where you can simply dump your homework. Share your efforts (e.g. post some code) and when you have a specific issue, you will likely get help solving it.

Comment: Lots of the components you have posted in your example look right, and are pretty easy! As Gilles said, we are not here to do your homework for you.